# Create multiple expanding blocks within the same page using HTML

Tags: html, menu, expandable

So, I needed to create a page that had multiple sections that could be expanded and collapsed independently of one another. I did my research awhile back and was able to "develop" this functionality:

```html
<h2><a style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="if(document.getElementById('ID') .style.display=='none'){ 
document.getElementById('ID') .style.display='';    
document.getElementById('IDtitle') .innerHTML='- (Collapse)';}     
else{
document.getElementById('ID') .style.display='none';document.getElementById('IDtitle') .innerHTML='+ (Expand)';}"><span id="IDtitle" style=" cursor: pointer; color: #7CA6C0;">+ (Expand)</span></a></h2>
<p>Visible content</p>
<div id="ID" style="display: none ;">
  My hidden content here
</div>
```

From this I can create multiple expanders that operate independently by copying the above and just changing the ID's. That was all fine and good when I had anywhere from 1 to 5 of these. Now I am working on a project where little bios are being added and I am looking at 45 of them on a single page. There has to be another way right? Is there a better way to do what I am doing?

Comment: Give Bootstrap a look - [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For now I will provide one solution, but with using jquery. Here you just need to add expandable elements to HTML, logic will be one for them all.

> [Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sk2krpks/)

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var clickedLink = $(this);
  var relatedContainerId = clickedLink.data('container');
  var relatedContainer = $('#' + relatedContainerId);
  if(relatedContainer.is(':visible')){
    relatedContainer.hide();
    clickedLink.find('span').text('+ (Expand)');
  }else{
    relatedContainer.show();
    clickedLink.find('span').text('- (Collapse)');
  }
});
```

Main Idea to set `id` of toggled container in link via [data-attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). According to this You will known what div you should open or hide.

---

UPD: The same without Jquery : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sk2krpks/3/)